# UDEV- Why echo not affect?

Tags: scripting, echo, udev

I trying to  echo something when my USB is plugged in with udev(rules). But echo seem not working or not affect while other command is working.

My script: autorun.sh

```
echo "-----------usb detect---------"
cp /home/root/data1 /home/root/data2
```

My rules file:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="16c3", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1536", RUN+="/home/root/autorun.sh"
```

What should I do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by:

```
echo "-----------usb detect---------" > /dev/ttymxc0
```